# Specify requirements for a REST server

Tags: web-services, rest, requirements

I am writing the requirements that a REST web-sever that needs to implement. One of the non-functional requirements is that each function (component) of the system can be activated or deactivated independent of the other ones.

To make it more clear, the web server offers different services, the services provider should be able to deactivate one of the offered services at any time without affecting the other ones.

Is there a word describing this specification that could be wrote in the requirements and make a developer understand the needs ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to programming

Answer (score 0):

> Is there **a word** describing this specification that could be wrote in the requirements and make a developer understand the needs?

No, there is no single word.